# SQL: Transforming an String into an Array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, split

I do have the following Table - ExampleTable :
[image: ExampleTable]

With the DbQuery:

```
let query = `
        SELECT *
        FROM "ExampleTable "`;
return this.dbQuery(query, []);
```

I do get an Array which looks as the following:

```
result = ["First":111,"Second":222,Third:"Yes/No/Unknown"]
```

Question: How to Transform the String: **"Yes/No/Unknown"** into an additional Array, so that the following can be achieved?

```
result = ["First":111,"Second":222,Third:["Yes","No","Unknown"]]
```

Comment: The easiest way in this particular case would certainly be to split it in Javascript after the query.

Answer (score 0):

If "first" and "second" are the primary key of this table, query below works. But it's easier to split array via JS

```
select first, second, JSON_ARRAYAGG(val) as third
from (
    SELECT first, second, substring_index(third,'/',1) as val
    FROM ExampleTable

    union all

    SELECT first, second, substring_index(substring_index(third,'/',2),'/',-1) as val
    FROM ExampleTable 

    union all

    SELECT first, second, substring_index(third,'/',-1) as val
    FROM ExampleTable 
) un
group by first, second
```